# Is it possible to define a calculated member in MDX (ex. Percent of Total) without specific dimension/hierarchy?

Tags: mdx, olap, cube

Is it possible to define a calculated member in MDX (ex. Percent of Total) without specific dimension/hierarchy? I'm wondering if there's an easier way to get the percent of total of several dimensions without defining a calculated measure for each.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy. One approach is described here: http://tomislav.piasevoli.com/2009/10/25/bitmap-index-universal-percentage-in-owc-take-2/